# reformat dataframe using openpyxl

Tags: python, openpyxl

I have a unformatted dataframe, that I would like to re-format using Openpyxl.

**Data**

```
id  consumed_q122   available_q122  consumed_q122   available_q222
aa  727.2           272.8           975.7           24.3
bb  0               1000            117.3           882.7
```

Desired

[image]

**Doing**

```
from openpyxl.styles import colors
from openpyxl.styles import Font, Color
from openpyxl import Workbook
wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active

from openpyxl.styles import PatternFill
    
sheet['A1'].fill = PatternFill(bgColor="808080", fill_type = "solid") #grey
sheet['B1'].fill = PatternFill(bgColor="FFC0CB", fill_type = "solid") #pink
sheet['C1'].fill = PatternFill(bgColor="FFC0CB", fill_type = "solid") #pink
sheet['D1'].fill = PatternFill(bgColor="add8e6", fill_type = "solid") #blue
sheet['E1'].fill = PatternFill(bgColor="add8e6", fill_type = "solid") #blue



I am researching how to:
1. make the header fonts bold and black
2. make the headers 'wrap text'
```

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: The code looks okay so far, though it's best to create the styles first and then assign them. Formatting is covered in the documentation. What do you need help with?

Comment: Thank you. Moreso making text bold, aligning them to be centered, and creating those borders. I did not see this in the documentation. Will keep researching,

Comment: https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/styles.html is pretty comprehensive.

Comment: Ill go through it thank you

Comment: The third column is probably `consumed_q222` instead of `consumed_q122`?

Comment: Yes you are right @Corralien

Comment: Did you solve your problem?

Comment: I am still working on it - haven’t solved it just yet

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I fail to laod your desired image. Refer to what you are working on:

1. headers fonts bold and black can be set by font
2. headers 'wrap text' can be set by alignment

   ```
    from openpyxl.styles import Alignment, Font

    font1 = Font(color=colors.BLACK,b=True)
    algn1 = Alignment(wrapText=True)

    sh.cell(row=1,column=1).font = font1
    sh.cell(row=1,column=2).alignment = algn1
   ```